# How to Display the tag content of Custom Post?

Tags: custom-post-types, tags

I have a custom post called "Portfolio" whith the taxonomies:
 - Categories
 - Tags (tag clouds)

I want to show the Tag content inside the custom post.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show us the code? Are you trying to call the tags within the portfolio posts themselves? the_tags should work within your custom loop: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the loop, insert **the_tags()** function, like this:

```
            <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="your_content_div">
                       <?php the_content();?>
                    </div>      
                    <div class="tagssss">
                       <?php the_tags();?>
                    </div>                      
            <?php endwhile; ?>
```